# HTML 5 Audio Current Position

Tags: html

Using HTML 5 together with the DOM is there a way to get the current location that the user is in playing an audio file and also later on go back to that position?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [HTMLMediaElement](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#htmlmediaelement) interface. `element.currentTime` should give you what you're looking for.