# HTML Audio - Detecting position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, audio

Is there anyway when using the HTML5 Audio tag to have an eventListener or action using Dom/jQuery to fire an event during playback or at the end?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596104/html-5-audio-current-position) answer links to currentTime but there are no examples, Pseudo code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="file.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("audio").addEventListener("end", function () {
        alert("song has ended");
    });
    $("audio").addEventListener('20.2', function () {
        alert("your currently at 20.2 seconds in the track");
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also saw this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830375/start-html5-audio-at-random-position - start HTML5 at a random position, there is some good code you can see across the site (click links on the right below) relating to this post and am sure you can find some good snippets and make a nice working simple script.

Comment: http://mindovermeta.com/2010/08/how-to-build-an-iphone-compatible-html5-audio-player/ and this site http://mindovermeta.com/demos/html5audio.php?step=2 - also very good examples of what I needed.. please check them out and other links on this page - more than enough information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

Get the duration of the audio and make an alert based on the currentTime and display alert wherever you require.

```
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){    
var duration = document.getElementById('duration');
var s = parseInt(audio.currentTime % 60);    var m = parseInt((audio.currentTime / 60) % 60);
duration.innerHTML = m + '.' + s + 'sec'; 
}, false);
```

Comment: I am happy with both responses but I can't vote answers up ATM. I marked this one therefore as the answer, the other post too showed clean code but could not rep.

Comment: Nice answer.  I was searching for how to detect some kind of "ended" event when a play range was specified and the end of the range had been reached. Your answer provided a solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `ended` event:

```
$("audio").on("ended", function() { 
     // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Is there a duration function?

Comment: I don't believe there is - at least not one that you can tell to fire at a specific point in the playback.

Comment: This was a helpful answer and clean code chunk, I have returned back to give you a plus point rep. Sorry it only has small value but your help was appreciated.